# How to make a base station that simply emit a beacon in OMNeT++ INET 3

Tags: omnet++, inet

Just as the title says:
I want a base station that broadcasts its name at regular intervals

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `udpBasicApp.cc`
This class explains how you can exchange UDP messages. With minor modifications, I believe you can get what your looking for, or at least close to it.